# How to warm ham and keep it moist

Tags: ham

If I bought a pre~cooked ham from the store and sliced it and put 3 lbs in a glass dish how long and at what Temperature should I use, so it doesn't dry out?~

Answer (score 1):

For a fully cooked, spiral sliced or sliced ham, I usually wrap the ham in foil and heat in a slow cooker on low for 2-3 hours depending on the size of the ham.  Otherwise, there should be heating instructions on the package concerning the temperature and length of time to cook per pound.